# Unable to dismiss CNContactViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to let the user create a new contact. While I've got the screen to prompt the user to put in all his details there is no navigation bar at the top(Like there is in the default Apple Contacts app). There is no way to exit the scene. I'm using the ContactUI framework in swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.3. Here's the code:

```
// create a new contact
    let createNewActionHandler = {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        let newContact = CNMutableContact()

        let contactPicker = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: newContact)
        contactPicker.delegate = self
        contactPicker.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
        self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Here's what I'm trying to get:
[Apple Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9nQc.png)

Here's what I have: 
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Ao0.png)

I'm launching the new contact view controller from an action sheet in a tab view controller. I tried embedding the tab in a Navigation view controller but to no effect. I even tried setting the setToolbarHidden property of the navController but it didn't help.

Thanks for any help. I saw the issue raised in other forums but they didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view controllers must be embedded in UINavigationController and you should push or show view controller:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(contactPicker, animated: true)
```

instead of presenting view controller

Answer (score 13):

You have to embed contactViewController to UINavigationController 
and Implement Delegate Methods.

```
let createNewActionHandler = {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    let newContact = CNMutableContact()

    let contactPicker = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: newContact)
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactPicker)
    self.presentViewController(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


//MARK: - Delegate

  func contactViewController(viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWithContact contact: CNContact?) {
      viewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }

  func contactViewController(viewController: CNContactViewController, shouldPerformDefaultActionForContactProperty property: CNContactProperty) -> Bool {
      return true
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are presenting contactPicker viewcontroller on top of current active controller, you will not have access to navigationbar as the view is presented fully,if you want to have button's as in Apple contact app you need to embed your presenting viewcontroller inside UINavigationController, and add left and right bar button items.

Refer the following apple sample which demonstrates the same.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Listings/Classes_RecipeAddViewController_m.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried all methods but none worked, So I made a custom method

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    private struct AssociatedObject {
        static var key = "action_closure_key"
    }
    
    var actionClosure: (()->Void)? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObject.key) as? ()->Void
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedObject.key, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            target = self
            action = #selector(didTapButton(sender:))
        }
    }
    @objc func didTapButton(sender: Any) {
        actionClosure?()
    }
}
extension UIViewController {
    func addDissmissButton(){
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Dismiss", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
        cancelButton.actionClosure = {
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton
    }
}
```