# CNUI ERROR Contact view delayed appearance timed out

Tags: ios, ios10

I am trying to show the Contacts add new contact view with the ContactsUI framework in iOS 10.
The code that I am using to present CNContactViewController  the is the following:

```
    let contactViewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
    contactViewController.contactStore = CNContactStore()
    contactViewController.delegate = self

    self.present(contactViewController, animated: false) {}
```

But every time I execute the code the app gets frozen and I get three + times the following error log:
[CNUI ERROR] Contact view delayed appearance timed out

Any explanation is welcome,

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: This happens only on real device, works fine on simulator for me. Is it the same for you?

Comment: This happens to me in Xcode 10.1's simulator.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I find a workaround. Just wrap your `CNContactViewController` in `UINavigationController` and all will be fine.

Special code sample for @JackRobson

```
let contactViewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
contactViewController.contactStore = CNContactStore()
contactViewController.delegate = self
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactViewController)
self.present(navigationController, animated: false) {}
```

Comment: Yes! just works with               
 let contactsNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactViewController)

Comment: Could you show the full code exert. I'm struggling to get this to work.

Comment: This works, I believe it’s a bug that was introduced with the iOS 10 SDK.

Comment: Well, It doesn't work anymore on iPhone X since the Cancel and OK button are at the notch level, behind the clock and network indicator... a tap on it doesn't do anything. EDIT : It works with the self.present(). I tried with navigationController.pushViewController()

Comment: Is your notch problem occurring only with the `CNContactViewController`, but not happening with the VC that is below it?

Comment: When I achieve to show the "CNContactViewController" from my table view "didSelectRowAt indexPath" HOW DO I GET BACK???? There is no way to get back to the previous screen (my TableView)

Comment: SOLVED!!!! -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390406/unable-to-dismiss-cncontactviewcontroller

Comment: If the operation is called by a modal presented ViewController I didn't find a way to dismiss.

Comment: Yeah, basically you have to implement the delegate's contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) function.  It will tell you once they save the contact, so you can dismiss the screen.  Agreed on the fact you can't do anything on the screen if you use a full screen modal - use a nav controller, and you're good to go.