# Presenting ContactUI CNContactViewController results in a privacy error and a CNUI error

Tags: ios, contactsui

I tried to programmatically present a CNContactViewController for a new contact, but I got error "Access to PassKit Shared Cache file denied. Please verify sandbox exceptions and/or file a Radar."  The CNContactViewController also did not present.

I check that I had all valid permissions, such as Privacy--Contacts in the info.plist and that I had gotten the permissions in my code.  I had.

```
let cnContactViewController=CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
vc.present(cnContactViewController, animated: true)
```

I expected the app to present ContactsUI's CNContactViewController with a contact filled in it's fields, but it didn't happen, and I got two error messages:
Access to PassKit Shared Cache file denied. Please verify sandbox exceptions and/or file a Radar.
and
CNUI ERROR Contact view delayed appearance timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the first error, "Access to PassKit Shared Cache file denied. Please verify sandbox exceptions and/or file a Radar", didn't have to do with the CNContactViewController not presenting.  To solve the problem of it not presenting, I used @Andrew Vyazovoy's post [CNUI ERROR Contact view delayed appearance timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748969/cnui-error-contact-view-delayed-appearance-timed-out) and put the CNContactViewController as the root view controller of a navigation controller and presented the navigation controller, and the CNContactViewController showed on the screen.  The privacy problem is unrelated.

Comment: Since nobody else has commented on the PaskKit part, would you consider editing the question? Saves the readers time and mental processing. TIA.

Comment: I thought it might help people because others could have the PassKit error at the same time as the CNContactViewController not presenting.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting same error, and i fixed by using below code

```
let vc = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
vc.delegate = self
let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            present(navigationController, animated: false) {
                print("Present")
            }
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like the UINavigationController is necessary.